# Permission denied: how to find the cause

Tags: permissions, mount, eclipse, executable

I downloaded http://eclipse.baeyens.it/stable.php?OS=Linux to `/mnt/data`.
This is a partition of my SSD that I use to install development tools. It's mounted by `fstab`:

```
# <file system>                 <mount point>   <type>  <options>           <dump>  <pass>
UUID=34e00814-6c32-4c6b-97b7-bc317f631907   /               ext4    errors=remount-ro   0       1
UUID=43826176-05aa-44e9-a375-551bb6006cdc   /home           ext4    defaults            0       2
UUID=89a7b0f1-f0c7-493e-b43e-3074c2d4f0ea   /mnt/data       ext4    defaults,user       0   3
/swapfile                                   none            swap    sw                  0       0
```

it's correctly mounted:

```
$ mount | grep /mnt/data
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user)
```

and it contents belong to my user:

```
mark@lab:/mnt/data/dev/Sloeber$ ls -l
totale 392
-rw-r--r--  1 mark mark 122245 ott  7 08:12 artifacts.xml
drwxr-xr-x  5 mark mark   4096 ott  7 08:12 configuration
drwxr-xr-x 57 mark mark   4096 ott  7 08:12 features
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mark mark 136646 ott  7 08:09 icon.xpm
-rw-r--r--  1 mark mark   9260 set 10 03:50 notice.html
drwxr-xr-x  4 mark mark   4096 ott  7 08:12 p2
drwxr-xr-x  8 mark mark  40960 ott  7 08:12 plugins
drwxr-xr-x  2 mark mark   4096 ott  7 08:12 readme
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mark mark  61176 ott  7 08:09 sloeber-ide
-rw-r--r--  1 mark mark    394 ott  7 08:12 sloeber-ide.ini
```

The `sloeber-ide` file is an executable, but it fails when I try to launch it:

```
$ ./sloeber-ide
bash: ./sloeber-ide: Permesso negato (Permission denied, in English)
```

I don't think the error comes from the file itself... I should have the rights to execute it. Perhaps it something related to the application itself? How to understand what it tries to do that my system refuses?

Comment: What does "mount" command show? Is it mounted with "noexec" option?

Comment: @jpezz, yes, the `mount` output is there. I didn't noticed the`noexec` option because I didn't set it. Should I explicitly add `exec` instead?

Comment: It did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The "exec" option must be used to execute commands on a mounted disk volume.